# How can I make my shell scripts run in a new console automatically?

Tags: bash

Hello I am running Ubuntu 10.04 and learning the ROS (Robot Operating System) which means that I enter quite a lot of shell commands

I am currently creating some BASH script files to make my work easier, but there are certain commands which **must be run in another console**.

So please tell me what commands I must write in my .sh file so that it can run it's commands in one window,then start another window in which it run other commands, but from the same .sh file

Or they could be in different .sh files they just need to run in different consoles.

Comment: Can you describe what you are wanting exactly ? Potential solutions include `screen` to running `gnome-terminal -e "command"` to running a command in the background, with nohup and the & `nohup command &`

Comment: For example I need to run the command 'rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node' in a new console then I need to run other commands in other new consoles. And I would like to do this from a single .sh file.

Comment: Also I forgot to add these commands should not run in the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run your script in another terminal emulator window, I suppose `gnome-terminal` with the command

```
gnome-terminal -x ./script
```

You could simplify the process defining a function in your `~/.bashrc`

```
start() {
  gnome-terminal -x "$@"
}
```

where can choose the name you prefer instead of `start`. You use the function in this way

```
start ./command arg1 arg2
```

(you need to restart the terminal for the shell to know about the new function).

As you can see, there is a little problem, the window closes once the command terminates. To avoid this you could wrap your command in a shell script and add a last line with a `read` command:

```
#!/bin/sh
# script

./command arg1 arg2
read answer
```

Then when you call

```
start ./script
```

it will not closes, waiting for your input.

Unfortunately, It is difficult to automate this in the `start` function.

Comment: Thank you all the replies have been helpful but I've found out that `ros` commands have a problem with `the gnome-terminal-x` command.

Comment: @BoraGeorge: I updated the answer to take into account the closing of the window.